# c#: Will this code get optimized out?

Tags: c#, compiler-optimization

I was reviewing some code given to us by a third-party outsourcing firm and ran across this little gem:

```
try
{
    int i = strOriginalData.IndexOf("\r\n");
    ////System.Diagnostics..EventLog.WriteEntry("i", i.ToString());
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    ////System.Diagnostics..EventLog.WriteEntry("ex", ex.Message);
}
```

My question is will the compiler completely optimize this out?  When I look at the compiled assembly in Reflector, it shows this:

```
try
{
    i = this.strOriginalData.IndexOf("\r\n");
}
catch (Exception exception1)
{
    ex = exception1;
}
```

The declaration for i has been moved to the top of the method, and additional declaration of type Exception is at the top of the method also.

So, since this code doesn't really do anything, I was wondering if the compiler is smart enough to see that this code does nothing and can optimize it out.

Comment: The compiler will not optimize it out, but these sorts of things can be evil for performance. If the code gets itself into a state where an exception is being thrown and then eaten, it will have drastic perf knock-ons for tight loops. And silently of course...

Comment: @chiba: I wouldn't consider that a performance problem, more of a correctness problem.

Comment: @Henk I'm thinking of something going a million miles an hour round a loop throwing, catching and then swallowing exceptions. I wouldn't mention it if I hadn't seen dodgy "debugging" code doing this many times before.

Comment: @chiba: Yes, but that is exceptional (and) bad code. I was warning against the myth that catch blocks in general are bad for performance.

Comment: @Henk Thanks for warning about a myth I was not trying to spread... I've unfortunately found the above code to be quite common from rookie devs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So, as you've found via Reflector, the *C# compiler* will not optimize it out. Whether the *JIT compiler* will is another question. But, I would guess the answer is almost certainly not.

Why? Because the JIT compiler doesn't know that `IndexOf` is a boring method. In other words, as far as the JIT compiler knows, `string.IndexOf` could be defined as

```
public int IndexOf()
{
   CallAWebService();
}
```

Obviously, in that case optimizing out that line would be bad.

Answer (score 6):

How would the compiler know that `IndexOf` had no side-effects?

So basically no, it's not going to optimize it out.

Answer (score 2):

No, it won't be optimized out.

On the other hand, it is a *very small* overhead. Compared to the cost of string.IndexOf() setting up the catch block is negligible.

There would be a cost if there ever was an exception, but that's not likely.